# How to know if the bluetooth module is activated by command line on Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, bluetooth

I am searching a way to know through a command line if the bluetooth module is activated on Windows OS.

Anyone would know a shell command or anything else?

**EDIT**

I found these tools on the net this morning which could work for me, but I am still searching a solution without third parties:

- http://bluetoothinstaller.com/bluetooth-command-line-tools
- http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bluetoothcl.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, a simple command line `ipconfig` display the bluetooth adapter if the module is activated

```
Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of scripts at https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-tell-if-a-computer-is-bluetooth-enabled/  They should be useable.

Note that'll detect the Microsoft Bluetooth stack -- I haven't tested them with the (getting rarer) Widcomm, BlueSoleil, etc stacks. Note also they detect the networking parts of the Bluetooth support but that shouldn't really matter.

Comment: Thank you for your link, helpful but I prefer the command line 'ipconfig"

Answer (score 0):

Trying using

netsh wlan>

as most adapters come with Bluetooth and Wifi together

Comment: Thanks, I have just tried your suggestion, but there is nothing about Bluetooth with command "netsh wlan show all"

Comment: Err I have eleven different Bluetooth dongles and all are Bluetooth alone, no WiFi. Some laptops have WiFi and Bluetooth on the same module however.